# Why is Windows 10 still blocking me from running malware?

Tags: windows, malware, dynamic-analysis, windows-10, virtual-machines

I am analyzing some malware on Windows 10. I installed FLARE VM, disabled tamper protection and disabled the virus scanner in the registry. However when I attempt to run a malware, Windows is still preventing me from running it. What am I missing to get this to work?

I disabled it by adding `DisableAntiSpyware` to`HKLM/Software/Policies/Microsoft/Windows Defender` and setting it to `1`.
[image]

Comment: How is it preventing it?  What messages do you see?  How do you know it's Windows? Have you looked at the Event Log?

Comment: Well I initially thought it was windows blocking it, but it is an older sample I am looking at so it just might not work on Windows 8/10/11. I did try Windows 11 and on 11 even with everything off Windows 11 still removes it from the machine. I had to add it to allowed threats. But it does not move itself to another folder like it should. I have a feeling it might just not work correctly on newer OSes.

Comment: I am going to try execute it using wine on my REMnux box.

Comment: It is also not making any network requests like it should.